# Is this SQL query syntax correct?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, (SELECT date FROM player WHERE 
date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM player WHERE name = 'Deuslegio') 
AND name = 'Deuslegio'), CURDATE())
```

Basically, all I am trying to do is get the latest row record's date of a certain player name
and getting the difference from today's date.  But according to the phpMyAdmin on GoDaddy, I am getting this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' CURDATE())' at line 1

Comment: Does MySQL allow select queries without a where clause?

Comment: I just want to point out that your first nested query is completely useless.  You're saying 'select date where date=date'...  The Date result will be the same as the date being passed in to the WHERE.

Comment: remember.. `DATE` is a mySQL reserved keyword, you should really use a different fieldname

Comment: I fixed the useless nested query, thanks Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using three parameters in your `DATEDIFF` function:

```
 1. dd 
 2. (SELECT DATE FROM player WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM player WHERE NAME = 'Deuslegio')   AND NAME = 'Deuslegio')
 3. CURDATE()
```

You may only use two.

[mySQL DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: I thought there were three?
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
dd = day

Comment: No, [only two params in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) You're thinking of MS Access' function.

Comment: I edited your link to point to the official MySQL docs rather than w3schools.

Comment: Thank you, MB. W3 is RARELY correct, that just happened to be one of those rare occasions.

Comment: Well, that worked.  w3schools got it wrong or something.
By the way, does it compare by days or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query a lot.  This is your query (as fixed by removing the `dd`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF((SELECT date
                 FROM player
                 WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM player WHERE name = 'Deuslegio'
                              ) AND name = 'Deuslegio'
                ), CURDATE()
               )
```

The following is equivalent:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF((SELECT date
                 FROM player
                 WHERE name = 'Deuslegio'
                 order by date desc
                 limit 1 
                ), CURDATE()
               )
```